# how to find the emails in given message and replace with XXXXX in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string, nsstring

hello i have stuck in one situation on strings  i have text consider as follows

Electronic mail, most commonly referred to as email or e-mail since c 1993,[2] is a method of exchanging digital messages from an author to one or more recipients. Modern email operates across the Internet or other computer networks. ex@ex.in Some early email systems required that the author and the recipient both be online at the same time, in common with instant messaging. Today's email systems are based on a store-and-forward model. Email servers accept, forward, deliver, and store messages. Neither the users nor their computers are required to be online simultaneously; they need connect only briefly, typically to a mail server, for as long as it takes to send or receive messages. some@email.com  Historically, the term electronic mail was used generically for any electronic document transmission. esample@some.in For example, several writers in the early 1970s used the term to describe fax document transmission.[3][4] As a result, it is difficult to find the first citation for the use of the term with the more specific meaning it has today.

in above give text there are 3 emails (ex@ex.in, esample@some.in,  some@email.com)  i have to find them and replace with XXXXXXXXX for security reasons.

Any suggestions will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Detectors.

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:labelText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];
```

It will find you urls and email addresses, but from that point it easier.

Comment: it seems working fine with all other things also like phone number, urls addresses etc. but i have stuck at the result how to get all the substrings from matches it gives NSTextCheckingResult how to go forward from here

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the sentence (create array of words). Then for each entry, if it matches some regular expression (or at a minimum, contains @) then find that entry in the sentence and replace with XXXX.

(Typing on phone, so don't remember exact code).

```
//*** Pseudocode

//1. Split sentence into array of words
NSArray *words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for word in words
if word contains @"@" {
   sentence = [sentence stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:word withString:@"XXX"];
}
```

Comment: i think it wont work because if we mention some one like @john then the above code replaces john to xxxx

Comment: i am trying to replace xxxxx to only emails, not any string which starts or contains @ in it

Comment: I mentioned that a regex is the better way, but at a minimum you can do contains @

Comment: in that case i agree with your code it will definitely work and it looks similar approach as Zaph  and Abhishek. but with @Avi Tsadok approach we can handle emails, links, phone numbers etc. i am following that. Any way Thanks for the quick response every one

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using Regex replace

```
NSString *string = @"Electronic mail, most commonly referred to as email or e-mail since c 1993,[2] is a method of exchanging digital messages from an author to one or more recipients. Modern email operates across the Internet or other computer networks. ex@ex.in Some early email systems required that the author and the recipient both be online at the same time, in common with instant messaging. Today's email systems are based on a store-and-forward model. Email servers accept, forward, deliver, and store messages. Neither the users nor their computers are required to be online simultaneously; they need connect only briefly, typically to a mail server, for as long as it takes to send or receive messages. some@email.com Historically, the term electronic mail was used generically for any electronic document transmission. esample@some.in For example, several writers in the early 1970s used the term to describe fax document transmission.[3][4] As a result, it is difficult to find the first citation for the use of the term with the more specific meaning it has today.";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"XXXXXXXXX"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSRegularExpression` with method: `replaceMatchesInString:`.

```
- (NSString *)parseString:(NSString *)original {
    NSMutableString *replacementString = [original mutableCopy];
    NSRange replacementRange = NSMakeRange(0, replacementString.length);

    NSString *pattern = @"\\S+@[^ .]+\\.[^ .?!]{2,}"";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                  options:0
                                  error:nil];
    [regex replaceMatchesInString:replacementString options:0 range:replacementRange withTemplate:@"XXXXX"];

    return replacementString;
}
```

The concept: space not-space @ not-space . non-space-!-?-. space
Note that email addresses may contain non-latin characters so requiring A-za-z is not a good method.

Comment: Note: The answer by @Abhishek uses a simpler method (which I recommend) but a more complex regex which may be more complex than necessary and won't match some new TLDs such as "business".